# Segfault on virtual inheritance without virtual destructor

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

Suppose we have the following virtual inheritance:

```
struct B {
    ~B() {}
};

struct C : virtual B {
  ~C() {}
};
```

Now, why does it crash on destruction of an upcast pointer created, e.g., by `std::unique_ptr<B>(new C());`?

Note: If `B::~B()` is declared `virtual`, then everything works fine.

Comment: because it is an undefine behavior

Comment: i would assume that without a virtual function you do not get a vtable that is needed for virtual inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether the inheritance is virtual or not, it's undefined behaviour to delete a derived class object via a pointer to a base class type, unless the base class has a virtual destructor. That's what `std::unique_ptr<B>` does - it has a statically typed deleter which invokes `delete` on a `B*` pointer.

As you say, it will work fine with a virtual destructor, so that such a deletion becomes well-defined. It will also work fine using `shared_ptr` rather than `unique_ptr`, since that has a dynamic deleter based on the pointer type it was initialised with, so when initialised with `new C()` it will invoke `delete` on a `C*` pointer.

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I was looking for. :) So having `struct C : B` would also lead to undefined behavior, right? I think I tried that and got confused with virtual inheritance because w/o at least it doesn't crash (compiled with Visual C++).

Comment: @Xlea: Yes, you'd still have UB with non-virtual inheritance. It's perhaps less likely to crash, and more likely just to leave the object in a not-quite-destroyed state, but still undefined.